# Questions concerning using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

I currently am reading in a string that starts with a number up to the next delimeter and testing if the string read in is a float. Now I have a few questions here as I believe my regex works I just think I am not using the proper method once it tries to do it.

my particular float will be in the format of

```
d+(.d+)?(E(+|-)?d+)? 
r'(\d+(\.\d+)?([E][+|-]?\d+)?'
```

Above is the regular expression I'm using and it is correct for the specifications I have set up, but my issue is that I will be reading in bad values and I want to print an error that either prints the whole string as bad or prints the part that passed followed by an error with the incorrect part printing. When I try I get the error print

```
  print "ERROR: %s" % m.groups()
  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I feel like I am missing something simple but I cannot figure out what.

So in summary I am trying to use the above regular expression to compare a read in number string to see if it is in the float form. If the whole string conforms I want to print it and if there is a bad part I want to print the whole string as an error or print the good part follow by printing the bad part out with an error message.

```
p = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\.\d+)?(([E][+-])?\d+)?')

def is_float(str):
m = p.match(str)
if m:
    print  (m.groups())
    return True
```

I have provided the piece of code I am working with perhaps there is an error there

Some sample inputs are:

```
3@33 //should print 3 then an error with @33 printed
3.435E-10 // should print the whole thing
0.45654 //should print the whole thing
4E-2 //should print the whole thing
```

Comment: `m.groups()` is an array, try `m.groups()[0]` (or just print `m.groups()`)

Answer (score 1):

`m.groups()` is an array. NOT a string, `m.groups(0)` is the entire match, `m.groups(1)` is the 1st set of capturing brackets in your regex and so forth.

Try:

```
print(m.groups())
```

To see the different values at play

---

### First thing

You're missing a closing bracket. It should be:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?([E][+|-]?\d+)?)
```

Notice the one at the end after the final `?`

I then tested it here:
https://regex101.com/r/jF1jX2/1 and it worked.

Comment: doing print(m.groups()) returns the same thing were it prints the first match but for some reason doesn't take the whole number. Just to be sure my regex is correct I am using 3.435E-10 but it is only printing out 3

Comment: That's a different error @bobHarding you need to share more of your code and more of the output for me to help.

Comment: I have added the code above. The string passed in is just read from a file that all I know about is if the first value in the string is a number. (So the task is to read the string in and test to see if the whole thing is a float. If it is return the float, if it isn't print the good part followed by a error message with the remaining part that is bad.

Comment: @bobHarding good! One more thing I need - can you give me some sample input? Then I can finally test your Regex and so forth

Comment: I have added some sample inputs. I know there is something wrong I am unsure of how to check to see if the whole thing matches or if a piece doesn't so that is also part of the problem. I really appreciate your help by the way!

Comment: @bobHarding that isn't how Regex works, error correcting is SIGNIFICANTLY harder to do, as is error detection. The absence of a match should tell you it is wrong. It looks like it should match the 3. let me check

Comment: Ok so if I do the match and then compare the length of the first match with the original string that will tell me if the whole string matched correct? because I could work around it using that.

Comment: see edits @bobHarding - note that `3@33` WILL match the `3` and stop. If you need start and end use `^yourregexhere$` the ^ means 'start of input' and '$' means end

Comment: @bobHarding loving the swastika avatar BTW! Don't forget to tick?

Comment: I see that and thank you for correcting it, upon testing it in regex101 I agree it does work, but when I run it I am still only printing 3 for the number 3.435E-10 when it should print the whole thing correct? I tried printing m.groups() and m.group(0) but neither produced the whole number

Comment: @bobHarding are you 100% sure about that? REGEX is greedy by default and it should match 3.435E-10 - in python. Did you try the ^ and $ I mentioned?

Comment: I go it working. I had commented out a piece of code for testing and that was producing the error thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please don't forget to tick if this solved it @bobHarding

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, I'd not bother with a regex at all. Given a string that is supposed to represent a float, I'd do

```
def is_float(str):
    try:
       f = float(str)
       return True
    except ValueError:
       return False
```

(BTW if the next step was going to be to convert an acceptable str to float,
just put the `try` .. `except` inline, use f if no exception is thrown and do whatever is appropriate when the exception is caught )

Also there's a mistake in your regex, in that it doesn't handle a leading "-" for a negative number (or a "+" for a positive one). `Try` ... `except` handles anything that you can throw at Python, using Python's rules.

Comment: There is no mistake the scenario I am using does not take negative numbers thus there is no leading + or - symbol ( I though I said that in the original post but I guess I lef it out my mistake). Will the f = float(str) account for a number like 3.453E-10?

Comment: Yes. Any string representing a python float constant gets converted.